# How to create program to flash PIC microcontrollers?

Tags: microcontroller, pic

I am working on a project where I need to write a GUI using c# to flash PIC 18f4550.

I know firmware programming using c. But this one requires me to go more deeper into the mechanism behind flashing. How should I approach this problem? Is there any resources that I can use to start with?

Do I need to create driver(PC) to make the communication between PIC and PC?
On pic side I need to modify the bootloader I think.

Thanks for the help.. Much appreciated..

Comment: What, exactly, are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I'm trying to create a software that will let me flash PIC 18f4550 with hex files.

Comment: Are you re-inventing the wheel for educational purposes, or is there any reason you don't want to use the existing software that does the job flawlessly?

Comment: Reinventing it for company purposes. The company work in cannot distribute the Microchip product with the Application and hardware they are developing. So planning on creating a GUI that can be distributed by themselves.

Moreover, for my educational purpose too I would like to learn this. I'm still a student doing internship at this company for few months.

Comment: There are other ways to solve that problem, though without going to this trouble. Have you heard of the [TEAclipper](http://www.flexipanel.com/Docs/TEAclipper%20PIC%20DS508.pdf)?

Comment: There is an open source application called [AVRdude](http://www.nongnu.org/avrdude/) for flashing AVR microprocessors. I am sure you could learn a lot looking at its source code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are using the USB-enabled [PIC18F4550](http://www.microchip.com/wwwproducts/Devices.aspx?dDocName=en010300), I recommend using an HID bootloader. There are working examples you can use as a basis for your customized firmware loader UI in the [Microchip Application Libraries](http://www.microchip.com/mal).

The paths to PC software and firmware in the current version (v2011-10-18):

```
<installdir>\USB\Device - Bootloaders\HID\
<installdir>\USB\Device - Bootloaders\HID\Firmware - PIC18 Non-J\
```

A USB HID bootloader is nice, as it allows the device to be flashed without special hardware, and Windows does not require driver / inf installation for HID devices. It is a comfortable way for your clients to do firmware updates on the field.

Comment: That is exactly what I did. I took their sample bootloader GUI and modified a bit for my purpose. Thanks!! :)

Answer (score 3):

It depends on what level you mean "flash" the PIC controller.

If you have a boot loader in the PIC device that has a protocol for accepting firmware updates, you need to implement the PC side of that protocol, using whatever link is available. For example, if the boot loader looks for firmware using an RS-232 protocol, you need to implement the server side of that. This will depend on what software you're dealing with in the PIC and how the PIC connects to the PC. If you can modify the boot loader, then you can implement an appropriate protocol on both ends to do software updates.

In the boot loader case you will not need a device driver on the PC side, unless you are dealing with some esoteric interface. I expect that the PC side of a boot loader update would be entirely in user mode.

If you want to flash a device without being concerned about the software in the PIC, you need to implement the protocols in the [flash programming specification](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/39622L.pdf). To do this you will need have an appropriate device on the PC side and software to control that device.